# Simplifying the given GCP BQ query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Can we minimize this big case statement in simplified one.**

```
case
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 1 MONTH)) then 12
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 2 MONTH)) then 11
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 3 MONTH)) then 10
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 4 MONTH)) then 9
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 5 MONTH)) then 8
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 6 MONTH)) then 7
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 7 MONTH)) then 6
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 8 MONTH)) then 5
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 9 MONTH)) then 4
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 10 MONTH)) then 3
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 11 MONTH)) then 2
    when EXTRACT(MONTH from GIVEN_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH from DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 12 MONTH)) then 1
  end as MONTH_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select given_date, 1 + mod(extract(month from given_date) + 5, 12) as MONTH_NUMBER
```

If to apply to some dummy dates  - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select 1 + date_diff(current_date(), given_date, month)
```

This makes a lot of assumptions, such as `given_date` being within a year.  If not, then modulo arithmetic probably does what you want:

```
select 1 + (date_diff(current_date(), given_date, month) % 12)
```

Comment: I am trying to capture range in numeric value.
For example Range: 07/2020 - 06/2021 then 

07/2020 should be 1 , 08/2020 should be 2 and so on  and finally, 
06/2021 should be 12.